How to improve my EventCenter to avoid memory leak?
Question
I Have an Event Center system, but cant automatically remove the event when subscriber be destroyed.
How to improve it?
IEventInfo.cs
    public interface IEventInfo { }

    public class EventInfo : IEventInfo
    {
        public UnityAction Actions;

        public EventInfo(UnityAction action)
        {
            Actions += action;
        }
    }

EventCenter.cs
    public class EventCenter: BaseManager<EventCenter>
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<EventType, IEventInfo> EventDic = new Dictionary<EventType, IEventInfo>();

        public void RegisterEvent(EventType eventType, UnityAction action)
        {
            if (EventDic.TryGetValue(eventType, out var info))
            {
                if (info is EventInfo i) i.Actions += action;
            }
            else
            {
                EventDic.Add(eventType, new EventInfo(action));
            }
        }

        public void CommitEvent(EventType eventType)
        {
            if (!EventDic.TryGetValue(eventType, out var info)) return;
            if (info is EventInfo i) i.Actions.Invoke();
        }

        public void DeleteEvent(EventType eventType, UnityAction action)
        {
            if (!EventDic.TryGetValue(eventType, out var info)) return;
            if (info is not EventInfo i) return;
            i.Actions -= action;
            if (i.Actions is null) EventDic.Remove(eventType);
        }
    }

Registering always use lambda func
Test.cs
public class Test: MonoBehaviour
{
        private void Start()
        {
                EventCenter.Instance.RegisterEvent(EventType.Test, () =>
                {
                        Debug.Log("Test");
                });
                
                Invoke(nameof(DestroyThis), 3f);
        }

        void DestroyThis()
        {
                Debug.Log("Destroy");
                Destroy(this);
        }
}


When subscriber is destroyed, Test() method still printing "Test"

When registering an event on an object that may have a longer lifetime, you also need to unregister it:
        private void Start()
        {
                EventCenter.Instance.RegisterEvent(EventType.Test, OnEvent);                
                Invoke(nameof(DestroyThis), 3f);
        }
        private void OnEvent(){
             Debug.Log("Test");
        }
        void DestroyThis()
        {
                EventCenter.Instance.DeleteEvent(EventType.Test, OnEvent);
                Debug.Log("Destroy");
                Destroy(this);
        }

Note that you either need to use an instance, static or local method, Or assign a lambda to a delegate field, to be able to successfully unregister any events. Another pattern is to wrap the unregistration in a IDisposable object, so the caller just needs dispose a returned object.
There are also solutions with weak event handlers, but they are somewhat difficult to use correctly and without any leaks.
